# Is vs. Are - Need help with use of this in a question

Tags: grammar, verbs, questions

What should I use for the following sentence:

How old is Nancy's grandparents?

or

How old are Nancy's grandparents?

Answer (score 1):

"are"

The answer would be "Nancy's grandparents *are* 65 years old".